# SD card slow on raspberry pi 3b, identical card is fast on nanopi r4s

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B and a NanoPi r4s.  I bought identical SD cards for them -- high endurance cards by Gigastone.  The rpi is running Ubuntu Server 22.10 and the nanopi is running Armbian 22.11.1.

[https://www.amazon.com/Gigastone-Endurance-Recording-Surveillance-Compatible/dp/B08HLY9GR5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HLY9GR5)

The sd card I/O is quite a lot slower on the rpi unit.  Anything I do takes 2-3 times as long on the rpi as when I do it on the nanopi.

Here are some details about each unit:

```
elyograg@gimli:~$ neofetch 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               elyograg@gimli 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.10 aarch64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.19.0-1011-raspi 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 37 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1060 (dpkg) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.2.2 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Adwaita 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Adwaita [GTK3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 1.200GHz 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      Memory: 203MiB / 904MiB 
elyograg@gimli:~$ ssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.

elyograg@gimli:~$ df -hl
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            91M  3.0M   88M   4% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   15G  8.4G  5.4G  61% /
tmpfs           453M  4.0K  453M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  183M   70M  73% /boot/firmware
tmpfs            91M  4.0K   91M   1% /run/user/1001

---

elyograg@legolas:~$ neofetch 
                                 elyograg@legolas 
                                 ---------------- 
      █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █      OS: Armbian (22.11.1) aarch64 
     ███████████████████████     Host: FriendlyElec NanoPi R4S 
   ▄▄██                   ██▄▄   Kernel: 6.0.10-rockchip64 
   ▄▄██    ███████████    ██▄▄   Uptime: 21 days 
   ▄▄██   ██         ██   ██▄▄   Packages: 667 (dpkg) 
   ▄▄██   ██         ██   ██▄▄   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
   ▄▄██   ██         ██   ██▄▄   Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
   ▄▄██   █████████████   ██▄▄   CPU: (6) @ 1.416GHz 
   ▄▄██   ██         ██   ██▄▄   Memory: 294MiB / 3862MiB 
   ▄▄██   ██         ██   ██▄▄
   ▄▄██   ██         ██   ██▄▄                           
   ▄▄██                   ██▄▄                           
     ███████████████████████
      █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █


elyograg@legolas:~$ df -hl
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           387M   40M  347M  11% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1   15G  7.4G  6.9G  53% /
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /tmp
/dev/zram1       47M   24M   20M  55% /var/log
tmpfs           387M     0  387M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Is there any way I can speed up the sd card i/o rate?  FYI, I have never hooked up a keyboard, mouse, or monitor to either unit.  All admin is done via ssh.

I suspect that the card reader in the rpi is slower than the one in the nanopi, but the speed difference I see is not small.  I have reloaded booth units from scratch with identical new cards and the same speeds are seen.

Comment: have you done any actual speed tests?

Comment: This will show the difference:
https://asciinema.elyograg.org/slow-sdcard.html

In both videos, I am doing the same thing.  Running aptitude, and once the menu appears, pressing U to update the package database.

Comment: have you done any actual benchmarks - running aptitude is not a useful benchmark

Comment: A build script that I created does an rsync as its first step.  This is the summary printed at the end of the rsync on each little computer: https://paste.elyograg.org/view/b08f76a4

Comment: so, the answer is, you have not performed any *actual* benchmarks on the sdcard

Comment: The source system for the rsync is the same in each case. The data resides on a filesystem using Dell hardware RAID1, two 300GB 10000 RPM SAS drives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141831/discussion-between-elyograg-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: but the two SBC's have different CPU's, different NIC's, different RAM, different .... they are just different ... you should benchmark the sdcards, using something like `fio`

Comment: or `iozone3` - just two examples

Comment: Running iozone. It's been at it for a while.

Comment: with trial and error on a system with very fast disks, I worked out how to get useful info from iozone.  I've had to restart the test on the two SBCs because I was doing it wrong, and they are a lot slower than a large RAID10 array made from spinning rust.  Which of the many graphs it produces would you like?  I can also bundle them all in an archive, your choice as to what format (zip, tar.gz, tar.bz2, tar.xz, etc).

Comment: Here's the iozone graphs.  for the rpi, nanopi, and a dell server with RAID10 storage.

Comment: Good benchmark test or not, I'm not sure I see a point here -- can't remember anyone claiming any model of Rpi is the *fastest* at anything.   Find existing benchmarks of the 3B SD card reader with a similar class card and match those tests; if they are strangely significantly slower than they should be, you have a question.  Otherwise you just have a sequence of observations.

Comment: Also, there's too much focus on the nanoPi here -- it's irrelevant, except to the extent that it personally motivated you to investigate the 3B's performance.  Anyone could come on here and  post a comparison to any computer at random.  Why not include your laptop in this? "Hey my laptop can do XYZ way faster!"  So what? Again, unless you can demonstrate that the SD card speed is significantly less than available tests for *the same hardware,* there's no question here.

Comment: If the two systems were in the same ballpark of performance, I wouldn't be concerned about a possible problem.  But I'm seeing consistent transfer rates three times faster on the other SBC, with exactly the same SD card model.  Everything I do from making an ssh connection to running a build script for haproxy and quictls, is very noticeably slower.

I don't have any other SBC hardware, so I can't compare this 3B with another 3B.  These SBCs were given to me, I have never priced them for purchase.